# jQuery $.get returning full Object vs just what I need

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

Here is my code:

```
var source;
source = $.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  return console.log(json);
});
```

The above is returning the full jQuery object vs the JSON I am requested. The response looks something like this:

```
abort: function ( statusText ) {
always: function () {
complete: function () {
done: function () {
error: function () {
fail: function () {
getAllResponseHeaders: function () {
getResponseHeader: function ( key ) {
isRejected: function () {
isResolved: function () {
overrideMimeType: function ( type ) {
pipe: function ( fnDone, fnFail ) {
promise: function ( obj ) {
readyState: 4
responseText: "{'Hello':'World'}"
setRequestHeader: function ( name, value ) {
status: 200
statusCode: function ( map ) {
statusText: "OK"
success: function () {
then: function ( doneCallbacks, failCallbacks ) {
__proto__: Object
```

Anyone know what I am doing wrong? I have been dealing with this for a couple of hours now :(

Comment: I doubt that `alert(json)` outputs this...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous, `source` cannot equal the JSON you are requesting, because it isn't available yet. `jQuery.getJSON` will return the `jqXHR` object it creates to deal with the request **and then** runs away and retrieves the response.

```
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
  // deal with response  here
});
```

Upon the response being available (**some time later**), the callback (the function you're passing) is executed, so you can access the response in there via the first parameter (which you've called `json`).

You can see this by trying the following:

```
console.log('1');

$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
    console.log('2');
});

console.log('3');
```

You'll see that your console will read 1, 3, and then a split second later (i.e. the time to perform the HTTP request), 2; This shows the getJSON response returning without completing, the script continuing to execute, and then the callback being invoked **some time later**.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up! I knew it was something I was simply overlooking... I ended up doing my logic with the successful return

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this:

```
var source;
source = $.get(url, function(data) {
  return alert($.parseJSON(data));
});
```

Comment: When I do that, I get `undefined` :(

Comment: `data` will already be JSON, there is no need (and you cannot) parse it twice.

Comment: It won't already be JSON since I am using `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON`. This method works fine for me so that's why I suggested it.

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.5, that method returns a jqXHR object (what you are seeing).  See the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object) for more info.

You can see that the JSON you want is actually in the responseText variable.  So it should be `source.responseText`.